# Date format while exporting csv file node js

Tags: node.js, csv, express

Is there a way to format the date "YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm:ss" when exporting to csv using csv-express? I've google this for a good amount of time but found nothing. I'm using the latest version of Node.js, Express and MongoDB.

This is the default date format: "Thu Aug 09 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)". I just want this "2018-09-09 08:20:32".

The final result needs to be: Exporting all users from database

Here's my query:

```
 app.get('/download/exports/users/:id', function(req, res){

        const fileName = req.params.id +'.csv';
        const file = `${config.csvFileDownload.url}${fileName}`;

        res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${fileName}`);
        res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/csv');

        res.download(file,  function (err){
            if(err)
                console.log(err)
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) module for formatting date

```js
const moment = require('moment')
const date = new Date() // example - replace with your dates
const formattedDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Hi @Redical Edward, thank you for your answer. Probably it works like that, but it outputs the current date and time. I need date and time from Database( working with MongoDb, mongoose for node js)

Comment: no its just an example, you can put your dates as well. this will help you : )

Answer (score 0):

This is simplest way to convert date PDT to "YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm:ss" without using any libraries.

```
var event = new Date("Thu Aug 09 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)");
 
let date = JSON.stringify(event);  //2018-08-09T07:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Answer could use more explanation. Also, move your comment to the answer.

Comment: Thank you @ColinMarshall for your suggestion!!